# How can we get 'multilayered' object using sequelize.js?

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

Let's say I have 3 tables on an existing mysql database; Song, Singer, Management.
I defined the tables on sequelize models (I use sequelize and sequelize-definer):

song.js

```js
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');

module.exports = {
  fields: {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: false,
    },
    title: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    singerId: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: true,
      reference: 'songs',
    },
  }
};
```

singer.js

```js
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');

module.exports = {
  fields: {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: false,
    },
    name: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    managementId: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: true,
      reference: 'singers',
    },
  }
};
```

management.js

```js
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');

module.exports = {
  fields: {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: false,
    },
    name: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
    },
  }
};
```

If I have 1 song on my DB:
id: 1, 
title: "Heavy Rotation", 
singerId: 1

1 singer on my DB:
id: 1, 
name: "AKB48", 
managementId: 1

1 management on my DB:
id: 1,
name: "AKS"

and a variable named songObj refers to Heavy Rotation song.
When I do songObj.getSinger() it will returns:
{id: 1, name: "AKB48", managementId: 1}

I want my code so it can return
{id: 1, name: "AKB48", management: {id: 1, name: "AKS"}}

Is it feasible on sequelize or other ORM?

Answer (score 1):

What you want can be achieved with Sequelize, you'll just need to modify your models' definitions to be more like the [recommended convention](http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/models/#import)

```
    module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
      var Song = sequelize.define("Song", {
        title: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull: true
        }
        // and so on ...
      });

      return Song;
    };
```

No id declaration needed. After that, and making the required associations, you could use [Eager Loading](http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/models/#eager-loading) to require the objects you need like this:

```
    Singer.find({where: { id: 1 }, include : [Management]}})
```

or even

```
    Song.find({where: { id: 1 }, include :
        [{
            model: Singer, 
            include: [Management]
        }]
    })
```

Comment: You're welcome @Nia, choose it as the best answer if working correctly, thanks